# Remove the lighting artifact from the triangles

Tags: modeling, light, lighting, geometry

I’m trying to make a 3d model like this, but there is a lighting artifact caused by the triangles:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to remove this lighting artifact?

Comment: Do you really need those triangles??

Comment: @Rajjaiswal Why not?

Comment: Because as far as I can see,those triangles are not doing any work there,also why are those edges marked sharp?... I may be wrong but from the angle from which you took the screenshot,they don't make any sense there

Comment: @Rajjaiswal Mark sharp doesn't do anything. If I just remove it, the same result.

Comment: @Rajjaiswal The sharp edges in the above screenshot don't relate to this issue. I'm asking how to remove those weird lighting artifacts from the triangles. If it doesn't need, how do I achieve similar results, only with quads?

Comment: @Rajjaiswal Why did you think that triangles not doing any work? Do you have any better ideas? I really don't want to put the edge loops just for a few vertices to make a curved line in the screenshot above. If that doesn't make any sense, that how to make this sense?